# Stop Cloudflare from hitting .mp3 files

Tags: caching, cloudflare

I am using Cloudflare as a DNS and have a site which has public .mp3 files alongside other assets such as images in the public directory.  Now Cloudflare IP's are hitting that mp3 file over and over again because they do NOT cache .mp3.

The problem is that over 6gb of bandwidth was used between just 3 Cloudflare IP's hitting that file!

Is it possible to tell Cloudflare to stop hitting these files?  Also I want to upload more mp3's in the future and the CMS uses a dynamic folder generation so I can't just specify the file paths.

Though the directory itself is

```
/storage/app/uploads/public/
```

and contains the mp3's files as well as website images.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Quick google search gave me the following urls; check this: https://helloacm.com/how-to-cache-audiovideo-mp4-using-cloudflare-cdn/  You can also add 3 page rules in free cf plan:  https://helloacm.com/how-to-offload-your-server-by-using-cloudflare-cache-everything/

Answer (score 1):

You should try a Page Rule in cloudflare. URL matching `*.mp3`. In that Rule tell it to explicitly cache those URLs.

Comment: But Cloudflare doesn't cache Mp3 files without the enterprise edition.

Comment: That being the case if you block cloudflare from hitting that file then users will get a 404. Have you considered using AWS for serving the mp3s?